# Subscribe on callback function javascript in WebBrowser Windows Phone

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have component `WebBrowser` and `javascript` function `start()` with callback:

```
 function start() {
      my_object.subscribe("chanel_name", function(data) {
               alert(data);
        });
   }
```

I can call my function:

> Browser.InvokeScript ("start")

but how can I subscribe on callback?

```
function(data) {
               alert(data);
        });
```

I want to use variable data in C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.external.notify to pass messages back to your app from the WebBrowser as in [this Blog post](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/11/windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control-script-notify/).  It only works with strings so you will have to do some JSON serialization to return your data.